# xcode ios: datareload not reloading row count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a list of books in table view. I then created a 'delete' and 'add' function to it.

The thing is that when ever I add or remove a data, I use [self.tableView reloadData]; to reload the table datas.

The problem now is that if I fixed the rows then the data is reloaded with no error, but if the row number is changed, then I gives out an error. After checking, I noticed it is the row number count that is not being updated. Any idea how should I do it? I am using [arrayOfNames count] in the numberOfRowsInSectionn and in my cellForRowAtIndexPath I update my row number. The row number updates on cellForRowAtIndexPath but the numberOfRowsInSectionn is not updated with the new row count

Answer (score 2):

You can't call reloadData without modifying the datasource.  If your data source is an array, you have to replace it with another array that doesn't have the element that the user just deleted.  Otherwise you'll return the wrong numbers in numberOfRowsInSection and your app will crash.

Comment: sorry but dont get what you mean here. I have run the same code to read the data from the web server and received them. So means I have to change the row count on numberOfRowsInSectionn manually?

Comment: You said your row number count is not being updated.  Where does that count come from?